# SQL Update Dynamic Based on Table?

Tags: sql-server-2008, dynamic, pivot, sql-update, rule-engine

I am trying to think through a way to do some rule-based SQL Update statements on a table. 
Things look like the below, which IMO is not really optimal:

```
create table #typeofchange ( TypeOfChangeId Int  , ChangeNote VarChar(16) )
Insert into #typeofchange values ( 0 , 'prepend' )
Insert into #typeofchange values ( 1 , 'replace' )
Insert into #typeofchange values ( 2 , 'append' )
create table #dynamicstuff ( DynColName VarChar(16) , RowValue VarChar(16) , TypeOfChangeId Int )
Insert into #dynamicstuff values ( 'Column_A' , 'xxxx' , 0 )
Insert into #dynamicstuff values ( 'Column_B' , 'yyyy' , 1 )
Insert into #dynamicstuff values ( 'Column_C' , 'zzzz' , 2 )
create table #thetable ( Column_A VarChar(50) , Column_B VarChar(50) , Column_C VarChar(50) )
insert into #thetable values ( '-1-' , '-2-' , '-3-' )
insert into #thetable values ( '-4-' , '-5-' , '-6-' )
insert into #thetable values ( '-7-' , '-8-' , '-9-' )

--      Dynamic transform to get this result set --
--      Column_A    Column_B    Column_C
--      xxxx-1-     yyyy        -3-zzzz
--      xxxx-4-     yyyy        -6-zzzz
--      xxxx-7-     yyyy        -9-zzzz
------------------------------------------------
```

The table schemata do not have to be this way. But I do need to figure out a way to do Update
statements against #thetable based on rules. I would rather not have to do dynamic SQL because
then checking return values and debugging is a pain.

Also, the actual #thetable has 144 columns, and can grow, so something with a case statement would be a problem I think.

I thought about changing #dynamicstuff to this, but I think it still walks me into a dynamic SQL trap:

```
create table #dynamic2 ( Column_A VarChar(50) , Column_B VarChar(50) , Column_C VarChar(50) , TypeOfChangeId , RowValue )
insert into #dynamic2 values ( 'dothis' , null , null , 0 , 'xxxx' )
insert into #dynamic2 values ( null , 'dothis' , null , 1 , 'yyyy' )
insert into #dynamic2 values ( null , null , 'dothis' , 2 , 'zzzz' )
```

Thanks for all ideas.

**Edit**

I think if I drop #dynamic and make a new table called #dynamic2, maybe I can make this work. Here are my tables now:

```
create table #typeofchange ( TypeOfChangeId Int  , ChangeNote VarChar(16) )
Insert into #typeofchange values ( 0 , 'prepend' )
Insert into #typeofchange values ( 1 , 'replace' )
Insert into #typeofchange values ( 2 , 'append' )
create table #dynamicstuff2 ( Column_A VarChar(50) , Column_B VarChar(50) , Column_C VarChar(50) , TypeOfChangeId Int )
insert into #dynamicstuff2 values ( 'xxxx' , null , null , 0 )
insert into #dynamicstuff2 values ( null , 'yyyy', null , 1 )
insert into #dynamicstuff2 values ( null , null , 'zzzz' , 2 )
create table #thetable ( Column_A VarChar(50) , Column_B VarChar(50) , Column_C VarChar(50) )
insert into #thetable values ( '-1-' , '-2-' , '-3-' )
insert into #thetable values ( '-4-' , '-5-' , '-6-' )
insert into #thetable values ( '-7-' , '-8-' , '-9-' )
```

I was thinking that I could somehow make a Union betwen #thetable and #dynamic2 to get everything in a single result set and then update in the table but I think I am still stuck with dynamic SQL.

Comment: The best way to do such processing is in a transact sql procedure.  1) Read each row from `#dynamicstuff`. 2) Issue an update statement on `#thetable`

Comment: Could you be more specific? Using a sproc is kind of obvious. Read each row means a cursor. Issuing an update when I don't know what column to touch means dynamic code, right? What exactly are you talking about?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you're going to be able to do this without dynamic SQL.  However if you could change the structure of `#thetable` and unpivot it to this:

```
CREATE TABLE #thetableunpivoted
(
    [RowId] INT,
    [ColumnName] VARCHAR(50),
    [Value] VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT  #thetableunpivoted
VALUES  (1, 'Column_A', '-1-'),
        (2, 'Column_A', '-4-'),
        (3, 'Column_A', '-7-'),
        (1, 'Column_B', '-2-'),
        (2, 'Column_B', '-5-'),
        (3, 'Column_B', '-8-'),
        (1, 'Column_C', '-3-'),
        (2, 'Column_C', '-6-'),
        (3, 'Column_C', '-9-')
```

then you could use a query like this:

```
UPDATE t
SET [Value] = CASE toc.[ChangeNote]
                WHEN 'prepend' THEN
                    ds.[RowValue] + t.[Value]
                WHEN 'replace' THEN
                    ds.[RowValue]
                WHEN 'append' THEN
                    t.[Value] + ds.[RowValue]
            END
FROM #thetableunpivoted t
INNER JOIN #dynamicstuff ds
    ON ds.[DynColName] = t.[ColumnName]
INNER JOIN #typeofchange toc
    ON toc.[TypeOfChangeId] = ds.[TypeOfChangeId]
```

which gives:

```
SELECT *
FROM #thetableunpivoted

RowId   ColumnName  Value
1       Column_A    xxxx-1-
2       Column_A    xxxx-4-
3       Column_A    xxxx-7-
1       Column_B    yyyy
2       Column_B    yyyy
3       Column_B    yyyy
1       Column_C    -3-zzzz
2       Column_C    -6-zzzz
3       Column_C    -9-zzzz
```